# Run Function App Locally (With Out Time Limit)

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, console-application

I'm aware the function App time limit is 10 minutes, and I'm aware that if my function is taking more than 10 minutes that I need to refactor.

However, I critically need run an importer function that only exists in my function app at the moment.  After I will refactor the code.

Is there a way to run my function app locally with out a max time?  My FunctionApp functions run functions that are not "FunctionApp" functions.  So, another work around could be to start my function app locally, and call a function manually (that is not a function app function).

I know this is rather confusing, but I'm pinched for time.

Is there a way i can call the "SynchronizeUsersService.SynchronizeUsers" function through a console command, or by adding this project as a reference to a console project?

Example:

```
public class SynchronizeUsers{
private readonly UserSynchronizationService _userSynchronizationService;
private readonly ILogger _logger;

public SynchronizeUsers(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, UserSynchronizationService userSynchronizationService)
{
    _userSynchronizationService = userSynchronizationService;
    _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<SynchronizeUsers>();
}

[Function("SynchronizeUsers")]
public async Task<HttpResponseData> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
{
    await _userSynchronizationService.SynchronizeUsers();
    var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

    response.WriteString("Users Synchronized!");

    return response;
}
```

}

Comment: If you're desperate, can't you just switch to a [higher plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#timeout) in Azure and remove the timeout?

Comment: I don't think the restriction is on the plan.  It times out at 10 minutes locally.

Comment: If you want to run it locally, then just consume the `UserSynchronizationService` in a console app, I don't understand why this is complicated?

Comment: Alternatively, in your local `host.json` you can set `"functionTimeout": "01:00:00"` to make it 1 hour. Or set a value of `"-1"` to make it infinite.